# Calling a form fails to initialize components - Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm having difficulty with a form in a Visual Basic forms application inside Visual Studio 2015.  I'm attempting to show the EditSeries form while passing a variable to it.  Here's the code:

```
    Private Sub btnEditSeries_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditSeries.Click
    Dim frm As EditSeries
    frm = New EditSeries(SeriesID)
    frm.SeriesID = SeriesID
    frm.Show()
End Sub
```

When I run the program in Debug mode, clicking on the EditSeries button produces a blank form with no controls or customization.  The person who is helping me learn coding (who has been coding for 20 years) is just as baffled; he suggested deleting and recreating the form, suspecting a break between the three core files that make up a form in Visual Studio.  I did that, but the behavior persists.

I have not been able to locate any references to this issue on the Internet, and I'm including screenshots of the blank form at run-time as well as a Design view of what it should look like.

[How The Form Should Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQDI0.png)

[Blank Form At Run-time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAboJ.png)

I first put the code to populate the data from the SQL Database in the "Form_Load" section, but that only produced a Null Reference Exception.  Moving the code to a button click allowed the blank form to show.

The goal is to pass a variable's value from the All Series form (seen in the background of the pic with the blank form) to the EditSeries form that will allow code to pull one, specific series's data from the database for editing purposes.

My thanks for your time and assistance!

Comment: Well, we know what a blank form looks like, we can't see the code you wrote.  An exception that's swallowed incorrectly tends to be an explanation, look at the Output window for a cue.  Don't just ignore a NullReferenceException, or do something arbitrary next, it is always a coding bug.  The form's design getting destroyed due to an exception at design-time is another, click the Show All Files button so you can open the Designer.vb file and see the InitializeComponent() method.

Comment: Well, you should not be trying to run a project that does not compile.  You normally get a warning about that but it is easy to click the "Don't show again" checkbox and you'll never see it again.  Fix the setting so this can't happen: Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run, "On Run, when build or deployment error occurs", select "Do not launch".   Best setting for the one above it is "Always build".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans's comment "it is always a coding bug" pointed me in the proper direction.

In my EditSeries.vb, there was the following code:

```
Public Sub New(seriesID As Integer)
    Me.SeriesID = seriesID
End Sub
```

I don't know if placement in the EditSeries.vb file matters, but it was located prior to the Form_Load section.  When I removed this subroutine, the form loaded as expected.

Many thanks to Hans Passant for pointing me in the right direction!